# shell decrement variable from external ifle

Tags: bash, shell, decrement

I'm trying do decrement a variable that i got from a .txt file and change it in that same file for the next time i run it!

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<cred.txt)
echo "Credits: $value"
if [ value -ge 1 ]
then
  DATE:'date +%Y%n%d'
  touch date.txt"
  value =$((value-1))
else
  echo "not enough credits"
fi
```

I've tried value =$((value-1)) but i doesn't seem to change anything.
So, the value of the variable is 200, the next time i run it i want it to be 199 and so on.

Comment: Variable assignments mustn’t have any spaces around the `=`.

Comment: What is `DATE:'date +%Y%n%d'` supposed to do?! I expect it will result in a _command not found_ error.

Comment: `touch date.txt"` has one too few, or too many, `"`.

Comment: `[ value -ge 1 ]` will compare the _string_ `value`. You probably meant `[ "$value" -ge 1 ]`.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is a great tool. And it’s faster than posting questions here and waiting for answers.

Comment: You are reading the value from your file and storing it in a variable.
Then you're decrementing the variable. But if you want to keep the result in your file, you've got to write it in the file, using someting like:
    echo $value>cred.txt
Otherwise it will remain in your variable and will be lost when you finish executing your script.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-LoupSabatier that was what i needed!